# Problem in exporting SSRS report to CSV format

Tags: sql-server, csv, reporting-services, export-to-csv, ssrs-2012

I have many SSRS reports, and all are having same issue while exporting data into CSV files. (Upgraded from VS-2005 to VS-2013)

I have some GROUP data on header while displaying the data based on condition like shown in below image:

[image]

While exporting Data into CSV format, their header data also getting download along with table-grid data. just like shown in below image (yellow shaded)

[image]

I actually want to merge those header columns with the actual data row, like shown in below image: (Yellow shaded)

[image]

**EDITED**:

I have found one solution to remove Header values from CSV. As setting the `DataElementOutput` to `NoOutput` (Shown in below image)

[image]

But still, not able to merge those header values into Data-Grid.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Might just be best to create some new columns and set them as hidden in the regular report.  That way, they should export to excel, but wouldn't show up on the regular report.

Comment: @Steve-o169: thanks for the suggestion. but actually in my older report in VS2005 from the same settings its working perfectly as i expected. but after upgrading the Report it has stopped working. strange!

Comment: @jap_jap - To which version, you have upgraded your reports?

Comment: @Aftab: From VS2005 to SSDT-2012 (in VS2013) I have upgraded

Comment: The csv renderer in SSRS 2005 is no more available since SSRS 2008. I am not sure if you still can export with the same rendering without any third-party extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the following official documentation:

- [Breaking Changes in SQL Server Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms143380(v=sql.105))

> **Redesigned CSV Data Renderer**
>
> In earlier versions of Reporting Services, when you exported a report to a CSV file format, the data was formatted in a way that preserved the way the data appeared on the report page. For matrix data regions, this resulted in a data format that was inconvenient to import into other applications in order to continue to work with the data.
>
> In this release, when you export a report to a CSV file, you can choose between two supported formats: Default mode and Compliant mode. Default mode is optimized for Excel. Compliant mode is optimized for third-party applications.
>
> **The earlier format for CSV files is no longer available**. However, for reports that do not use matrix data regions, **you can use Compliant mode to get a file format closest to the earlier CSV file format.**

It looks like that the SSRS 2005 CSV renderer has gone through major changes in SSRS 2008 R2 with the support for new features.

**Workaround**

Check the following question, were they provided an extension to reporting services that add the old csv renderer:

- [Force SSRS 2008 to use SSRS 2005 CSV rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902640/force-ssrs-2008-to-use-ssrs-2005-csv-rendering)

**References and helpful links**

- [MSDN - How to force SSRS 2008R2 to use the SSRS 2005 CSV rendering mode](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3511e680-7706-45e7-a3d8-0faa414ea38f/how-to-force-ssrs-2008r2-to-use-the-ssrs-2005-csv-rendering-mode?forum=sqlreportingservices)
- [Reporting Service 2008 - CSV export](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6f89e5e7-a3f5-42d1-9939-eddbf55fbfd1/reporting-service-2008-csv-export?forum=sqlreportingservices)
- [How do I export a SSRS matrix to CSV without losing the structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940692/how-do-i-export-a-ssrs-matrix-to-csv-without-losing-the-structure)